# Is it really possible to identify an user even on ALL browsers? (Including tor/brave)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

There's a website that identifies me on every browser I have used so far. (Mozilla, Chrome, Tor, Brave). I noticed that the website uses Indexed DB. When I tried to clear this stored data on my files, it refreshed itself right after loading the website. So, should the problem be Indexed DB?

What did I do?

Clear my cookies including local/flash cookies

Use Tor/VPN

Change IP (I get new IP whenever I reboot my modem)

Try a different browser (all)

Comment: you are being identified by your IP address.

Comment: @Moab My IP is not static. It changes whenever I reboot my modem.

Comment: So your question is basically how to circumvent their multi-account protection?

Comment: @gronostaj I did not create multiple accounts *on purpose*. However, my goal is to get rid of this protection, so yes. I want to know how it would be possible to identify me on all browsers. I also read about "browser fingerprinting" but am unsure if my problem is related to that.

Comment: @gronostaj Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to clean indexed DB for a specific website? Can I do that by uninstalling the browser, for example?

Answer (score 0):

They're probably using [evercookie](https://samy.pl/evercookie/) or something similar.

The goal of privacy-oriented browsers like Tor Browser is to make you anonymous, not untrackable - so websites can't tell who you are, but they *can* tell you are the same person who visited them before. Brave comes with some tracking protection, but still there are plenty of web APIs that websites can use (it can block some social and advertising networks though).

Even disabling JavaScript doesn't give you full privacy because tracking is possible to some extent using only the HTTP protocol which is the foundation of modern Web. For example cookies can be accessed and modified server-side. Heck, [someone built a chat that works without JS](https://github.com/kkuchta/css-only-chat).

TL;DR If they try hard enough, they can track you no matter what.

Comment: I have two questions if you could reply. 1) How do we clean evercookies? 2) Do you think that they might have stored some info such as canvas, webGL (browser fingerprinting)?

Comment: Cleaning is almost impossible, that's the point. Easiest way would probably be to reset browser profile. Fingerprinting is unlikely, because fingerprints may not be unique and some solutions are built to not have unique fingerprints.

Comment: Resetting browser profile did not work.... but I reset browser profile only for one particular browser.